# Solr indexing of multiple spatial fields (with polygons) produces errors

Tags: solr, polygon, spatial

We got the following problem. When we try to index polygons together with their centroid in one document only a few documents are indexed, most of them return the error:

```
com.spatial4j.core.exception.InvalidShapeException: Ring Self-intersection at or near point (10.4592,​ 49.921,​ NaN)
```

When we index only the polygons everything works fine. When we index only the centroids everything woks fine. But when we index the polygons in one SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType and the centroid in another SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType we get the errors for a lot of polygons. Out of around 13000 polygons only ca. 3000 are indexed the other documents produce the error.

We are using the latest Solr 4.5  version.

Comment: As I double-check the code, it's hard to see how your error could happen.  Could you please supply a simple input document in Solr UpdateXML format that demonstrates the problem? If you don't want to share publicly then send it to me directly.

Comment: Sry for the wait but we kind of found the answer to this. It seems our polygons were indeed self-intersecting, solr couldnt handle this. This seems to be intended although mongodb for example in the newest version allows self intersecting-polygons to be stored. Sry for the bothering you.

Comment: You can use JTS to buffer(0) them, which often resolves it.  This and other techniques are on the JTS FAQ.

Comment: Guys does geofit work with circles ?